# Node form – self changing theme

Tags: forms, theming, nodes

I'm adding different way of node editing so I have this code in my module:

```
$items['node/%node/edit-full'] = array(
'title' => 'Full edit',
'page callback' => 'node_page_edit',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => 'node_access',
'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
'weight' => 0,
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'));
```

What is disturbing.. it changes theme from admin to regular. Instead of Seven Theme I see regular website theme. Am I missing some variable in my definition?

Comment: ( I know there's "theme callback" but for other menu items this isn't needed, and behaves ok )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [`hook_admin_paths()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7) to tell Drupal to use the admin theme for your URL pattern:

> Modules may specify whether or not the paths they define in hook_menu() are to be considered administrative. Other modules may use this information to display those pages differently (e.g. in a modal overlay, or in a different theme).

In your case the code would look a lot like this:

```
function MYMODULE_admin_paths() {
  $paths = array(
    'node/*/edit-full' => TRUE
  );
  return $paths;
}
```

Once you've cleared the caches your pages should now be using the admin theme.

Comment: Awesome! In other module I used "admin" in path - that's why :) Fast & accurate - Have a nice day!